# Text Component numberOfLines default value?

Tags: react-native

I just want to know the default-value for `numberOfLines` attribute of the `Text` component ? something like 'auto' or 'initial' ...

```
<Text numberOfLines={selected ? 0 : 1}>{term}</Text>
```

`term` can some short or long  Arabic text

```
const term = 'هذه الكلمات مكتوبه باللغه العربيه';
```

Any help ?

Comment: I don't understand, what's the problem, what do you want to know?

Comment: default valueu for numberOfLines param .... I tried 'auto', 'initial' ... but it didn't work

Comment: Have you tried `undefined`? If it doesn't have a value then the component will use whatever it's default value is internally (which I guess doesn't have a value, but is rather just based on the size of the text & the component styles).

Comment: @Jono ... tried it ... but didn't work unfortunately ...

Answer (score 1):

There's no default value for  `numberOfLines`. If you want to have infinite `numberOfLines` based of condition you can just put the number `0` to it:

```
numberOfLines={someCondition ? 1 : 0}
```

Comment: It only works when the text fits into more than <<2 lines>> ... but when the text fits in one line ... it makes the Text completly disappear ... but thank you anyway

Comment: Can you post the code you are using and the text you are trying to render? so i can check it myself?

Comment: Which one is the string that is making the text completely disappear?

Comment: The one that already fits in one line .. I mean when numberOfLines = 0 and text is a single line

Comment: One more thing worth mention... your solution works perfectly with <static text> ... but produces the issue I talked about with <<dynamic text>>

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with static and dynamic text. I've tested this on my code both with fixed and dynamic text. Do you get something different if you use null instead of 0?

Comment: dynamic text => text I get at run-time ... variable ... static text: some harded coded text

Comment: That shouldn't do anything anyways, unless the text comes in some strange format. Can you paste the text that's not shown when you are using my solution?

Comment: The text that caused the isssue is Arabic Text ... no matter it's dynamic or static ... it just dodn't work

Comment: But you see the text if you put a static numberOfLines={1}

Comment: But disappear with numberOfLines={0}?